# Reuse of app name in iTunes Connect gives me validation error

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

This is the scenario:

We have had an app on App Store for years:

- bundle id: com.acme.theapp
- App name (in version details): The App
- Version 2.1

We recently released another app:

- bundle id: com.acme.newapp
- App name (in version details): The New App
- Version 1.0

Now, the new app is the one that we want to promote, so we would like The New App to take over 
the old app name "The App". In order to do this, we first released a new version of The App, renaming it to "The Old App":

- bundle id: com.acme.theapp
- App name (in version details): The Old App
- Version 2.2

and we created a new version in iTunes Connect for the new app:

- bundle id: com.acme.newapp
- App name (in version details): The App
- Version 1.1

So far, so good. It seems like we could "reclaim" the app name. However, when I create a dist package and validate it, it seems like the validation is making some kind of lookup on "The App" and finds the old app. On the screen before validation when I choose the provisioning profile, the headline is "Application: The App 2.2 (iOS App)", which of course is wrong. And when i click the Validate button I get an error:

```
"This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the 
previous version. If you wish to change your bundle identifier, you will need
to create a new application in iTunes Connect."

"Version Mismatch. Neither CFBundleVersion['133'] nor
CFBundleShortVersionString ['1.1'] in the Info.plist match the version of the
app set in iTunes Connect ['2.2']"
```

Somehow, the name "The App" is still somehow connected to the old app.
BTW, the bundle identifiers are correct, i.e. they have no changed in either of the apps.
Also, the apps are using the same developer account.

Is it impossible to reuse app names?

Comment: The error seems to be about the bundle ID, are you absolutely, positively sure that the bundle ID hasn't changed? I think by default it has a reference to the app name in it which changes if you change the app name.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Actually, I haven't changed any names in the xcode project at all. The only name changes, both for the old and the new app, has been done in "Version info" in iTunes Connect. I'm only interested in changing the name visible in App Store. But somehow, it seems that xcode makes a remote lookup by name to app store and gets a result that contains the old app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Actually, the name reuse did work**. There was some temporary hickup in iTunesConnect that didn't let me choose which app to upload, that's why the bundle id:s didn't match.

The name that I reused was the localized app name. I could reuse the old name after the name change of the old app had been completed and approved by Apple.

Note that you always have a localized app name, even though you are only using one language in your app. The localized app name can be edited for new versions by clicking the button "View Details" and then clicking the Edit-button next to "Metadata and uploads". The field name is simply called "App Name".

Answer (score 0):

A name for an app cannot be reused. I would suggest you to change the name slightly. If the name was "The New App", you could change that name to "The New App." and the dot would work, for example.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like app names can be reused if the old app is removed from app store, but are you saying that it can't be reused after renaming?

Comment: That is what I thought. I am going to look for info on the Internet about it. If that is the case, it depends on Apple: their server has the name of your app still. You could contact them and see whether they could remove the version from the server. I think it is not probable that they do that, though.